# Back key takes me two forms back in Blackberry using LWUIT

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

I have an LWUIT app which i am trying to port on blackberry. I have an issue with the dialogs. When any dialog is visible and the user presses back key, it takes me two forms back. One is dialog, which is disposed, and the other is the form from which the dialog is invoked. I want only the dialog to be disposed. Please help.

PS: I am using LWUIT 1.4 source code in my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override `back()` method and only to do a dispose of the dialog (don't call super method)